# Reasons for the awk script (to implement vlookup) showing "NA" for all the matches while processing tsv files

Tags: awk, vlookup

I have two files wherein file1 spans around 6000 lns containing Id matching value and file2 1000lns containing ID. I want to retrieve value from file1 for only those IDs in file2.

`file1.tsv`:

```
RtGene0001      rt_000005300
RtGene0002      rt_000005400
RtGene0003      rt_000005500
RtGene0004      rt_000005600
RtGene0005      rt_000005700
RtGene0006      rt_000005800
RtGene0007      rt_000005900
RtGene0008      rt_000006000
RtGene0008      rt_000006100
RtGene0009      rt_000006200
```

`file2.tsv`:

```
RtGene0006
RtGene0007
RtGene0013
RtGene0014
```

Expected output:

```
RtGene0006      rt_000005800
RtGene0007      rt_000005900
```

I have tried few awk scripts but they keep showing in NA in the value column.

scripts:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} FNR==NR {a[$1]=$2; next} {print $1, (($1 in a)?a[$1]:"NAN")}' file1.tsv file2.tsv
```

Output I got:

```
RtGene00NAN
RtGene00NAN
RtGene00NAN
RtGene00NAN
RtGene00NAN
RtGene00NAN
RtGene00NAN
RtGene00NAN
RtGene00NAN
RtGene00NAN
```

```
awk -f filename1.awk file1.tsv file2.tsv 
filename1.awk
BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} 
FNR==NR{
  a[$1]=$2
  next
}
{ if ($1 in a) {print $1, a[$1]} else {print $1,"\t", "#NA"} }
```

Output I got:

```
RtGene0006              #NA
RtGene0007              #NA
```

Kindly help me address what I could be missing and give suggestions on how to work around the issue.

Comment: Your first demo shows `file.tsv` instead of `file2.tsv`. When I run it with `file2.tsv` as the second file I get `RtGene0006 rt_000005800`
 `RtGene0007 rt_000005900`
`RtGene0013 NAN`
`RtGene0014 NAN`

Comment: Similarly for your second example I get `RtGene0006 rt_000005800`
`RtGene0007 rt_000005900`
`RtGene0013   #NA`
`RtGene0014   #NA`

Comment: The `file1.tsv` example you show seems to be space-separated, not tab-separated. With that change, I get results which look more like what you report. Is your problem that your TSV is not actually tab-separated values?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. I have edited it. I thought it would run seamlessly, however when I try to run them I am getting NAN/NA instead of  matching values

Comment: I did awk -F"\t" '{print $1}' on both files separately and got the first column. I confirmed them to be tab separated. I

Comment: Demo: https://ideone.com/nJvRI5

Comment: Your demo was so helpful to confirm my code. I guess it is the problem with my file. The ending of my file1. tsv `RtGene0022^IRtart_000007800$` whereas file2 `RtGene6226^M$`
`RtGene6386$`. Not sure how to work around this.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was able to fix it using `tr -d '\015' <file_test.tsv > file_test2.tsv`